# monotouch iPad - Convert exisiting iPhone project?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios

I have an existing iPhone project in MonoTouch 1.9 running on MonoDevelop 2.2.1.

How do I get it to open in the iPad simulator and how do I convert the project so that it only runs on iPad?

Comment: Correct, .NET iPad app developement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new MonoDevelop (released today, version 2.2.2) you can do this on the settings for your iPhone application.